# macOS Catalina doesn't allow MAMP permission to certain folders (Documents, Downloads, Desktop)

Tags: macos, permission, catalina, mamp

I have been using MAMP for a few years now, I just updated to macOS Catalina, it seems that macOS Catalina is blocking permissions to the Documents folder among a few others (such as Downloads and Desktop).

I have already checked the permissions on these files with terminal and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Additionally I have

The server gives me this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /Users/xxx/Downloads/index.html on this server.
```

The Apache log gives me this error:

```
[Wed Oct 09 12:31:30 2019] [error] [client ::1] (1)Operation not permitted: file permissions deny server access: /Users/xxx/Downloads/index.html, referer: http://localhost/Users/xxx/
```

It seems to be an issue with the way macOS is restricting permissions to certain directories. In the settings panel under Security and Privacy there are additional settings for file access, I have granted MAMP those permissions, in addition I have also went inside the MAMP folder and granted Apache's httpd the same permissions, still no luck.

Does anyone have a work around? This is causing me such a headache in development.

Comment: When I start MAMP it asks for Admin password and then runs perfectly. Are you using new MAMP?

Comment: Yeah, it's not that. As Johan van Dam posted below, it seems to only be a bug on port 80. Switching ports seems to be the best fix for this problem currently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same issues. Updated MAMP to the latest build (5.5). Also switched the ports back to MAMP default ports (8888). That worked for me. Also checked if some diffrent server was running on port 80 `lsof -nP -i4TCP:80 | grep LISTEN` but nothing seem to be using port 80. Could it be Catalina has a new security setting for this?

Comment: For the record resetting to default ports completely solved it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Catalina has more restrictions on system folders which we can apply an exception:

1. Open System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Privacy tab -> Full Disk Access -> Press 'Unlock to make changes' padlock
2. Open Finder Window -> "Go" menu -> "Go to folder" -> type "/usr/sbin/"
3. Drag the file "httpd" to the list inside the Full Disk Access settings.
4. Restart Mamp servers

[image]

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: I've been banging my head for hours and this very very simple solution solved the issue in 30 seconds!

Many many many thankyou!

Comment: Not working for me just now it seems, not sure why not.  Tried adding /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd as well just in case, but no dice.  I guess I'll just revert to port 8888 for now.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here.

Solution: Move your folders into another path (example: Home), don't use Documents or Download or other system folders.

enjoy

Comment: Thanks - I was using documents and had the same issue - moved that now and its all working :)

Answer (score 3):

Also had Apache not starting after upgrade to Catalina. I had my websites originally located in subfolders of the `/Users/***/Sites/` folder, and according to this thread, made a new folder `/Users/***/Repos` and moved all websites there and updated MAMP Pro doc roots for all hosts. That didn't allow Apache to start.

After that, I found this info:

> Check your Template folder, located in /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/template/httpd.conf.temp. Rename this file to httpd.conf.temp.bak and try to restart your Apache server.

on this page https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215197286-My-Apache-Server-will-not-start-

and after doing that, Apache in Mamp Pro was able to start on Catalina.

Comment: There's nothing in that folder for me

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue after update but didn't find any solution yet. For now I moved all my projects into a new folder in root. This one worked for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Several applications (GIMP for example) are not working also (they can't access "special" folders like: `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents` and `~/Downloads`, but other locations seem to work OK). I believe this is a "complementary feature" bestowed by the newly-released Catalina.
Update Different.

Comment: Sorry, not helpful.

Comment: You deserve to have a view, but I've stated clearly `but other locations seem to work OK`, @stack-delay

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem too. Same as @ecraciun I have moved my project into /Users/MyUser/Project and now it's work!

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of a permissions problem with your user/home folder, which should have chmod 750 permissions.

To verify them, open Terminal.app

```
cd /Users
ls -l
```

You home folder should show:
drwxr-x---+

Note:
rwx = 7 (read, write, execute)
r-x = 5 (read, execute)

If it doesn't, run this as sudo. (You don't need to allow Group write access, and shouldn't.) The '5' in this command is what allowed MAMP to read the directory for me.

```
sudo chmod 750 homeFolderName/
```

Also, it didn't work for me until I put an index.html file in the localhost folder that MAMP was trying to read.